# Calculating the shortest distance(perpendicular distance) between a point and a line

Tags: python, geometry, pseudocode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

Hi,
I have a point, `A`, and a Line with two endpoints, `B` and `C`.
I want to know how I can calculate the shortest distance between point `A` and the line between the points `B` and `C`.
Pseudo-code is enough, though Python is preferred.
Thanks

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged as a Java question. Please remove the java tag.